# joomla 2.5 tp=1 shows "object arguments" instead of real position names

Tags: templates, positioning, joomla2.5, template-engine

I have seen different templates that doesn't let us see their position names. When I add `?tp=1` to website link, they show `[object arguments]` instead.

I think these frameworks use T3 template engine (?). [what ever T3 is, it doesn't matter for me]

**I'm not looking for these answers:**

- Please tell me what the template name is? Visit its official demo url (for example http://joomla17-templates.joomlart.com/ja_elastica/?tp=1 or another demo) **This is not a real answer!**
- Update your template! This is not also a working answer. It doesn't matter to template updgrades. Because [I can see somebody in the link that has updated his template, but that hasn't worked](http://www.joomlart.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-68263.html).

---

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately also the official demo of the template has the problem: http://demo.bowthemes.com/bt-arise/?tp=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second link had the answer -

> I enabled that plugin, 'System - Language Code' and lo and behold, the template module positions were back.

I'd start with that because the T3 framework definitely displays module positions.

Comment: Plugin is already updated. Unfortunately in this case, the problem is with the official demo of the template! Thanks anyway

Comment: I accept your answer and hope correct templates (not like mine) be solved with your answer.